# How to solve "Zero-One" multiple coding Solution?

Tags: algorithm

Given a number N, find the smallest "zero-one" number S that is a multiple of N. A "zero-one" number consists of the digits 0 and/or 1.

E.g. If `N=4` then `S=100`
Here `100` is smallest integral multiple of `4` whose representation consist of only `0`and/or `1` digits.

I tried doing it in a brute-force way, but I'm looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: Is this a project euler question?

Comment: No. I came across this question in one of the job interview.

Comment: I guess that's all about **decimal** representation? or maybe **binary** representation counts too? :) (consider it a joke, but still..)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388165/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-1-which-is-divided-by-a-give

This is an approach may help....

Answer (score 17):

You need to search for the smallest number to multiply `N` by.

I would construct the number incrementally, starting from the least significant digit.

Supposing N=7. What are the possible least significant digits of the multiplying number? It will be a number which, when you multiply by 7, will have a result with the least significant digit of 0 or 1. If you try the numbers from 0-9, it can only be '0' or 3'.

```
+-------+--------+------+
| Digit | Result | Pass |
+-------+--------+------+
| 0     |  0     | Yes  |
| 1     |  7     | No   |
| 2     | 14     | No   |
| 3     | 21     | Yes  |
| 4     | 28     | No   |
| 5     | 35     | No   |
| 6     | 42     | No   |
| 7     | 49     | No   |
| 8     | 56     | No   |
| 9     | 63     | No   |
*-------*--------*------*
```

Then you try the second least significant digit. You will now try 00, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 and 03,13,23,43,53,63,73,83,93. The successful candidates will be the ones when, multiplied by 7, produce a number in which the two least significant digits are 0 or 1. You are left with '43', '30', '00', and '01'.

Repeat this process with the 3rd digit, finding the number which produces a multiple with 3 least significant digits meeting the qualities.

During the process you will find a number in which ALL of the digits meet the qualities, and that's your answer. In the case of N=7, you've found it by the 3rd digit. (7 * 143 == 1001).

Comment: For the input 3456 the above algorithm would return 11111011110000000, whereas the correct answer is 11011111110000000

Comment: @AnukuL: I tried my algorithm on this number, and at first it looked like you were correct. Then I realised there was a bug in my implementation: 0625 * 3456 = 2160000', but then when I appended a '9', my code created 9625, rather than 90625. Once I fixed this bug, I got 3456 * 3186085390625`. Check your implementation to make sure it handles zeros correctly.

Comment: @AnukuL: Here's my implementation of the algorithm. Note that I store values as strings, not numbers. That ensures I don't lose the trailing zeros. https://github.com/AndrewShepherd/zero-one-coding-solution

Answer (score 5):

Here is an alternative approach using BFS.

Starting with a root node with value `1`, you build a decision tree of whether to append a 0 or 1. Each node hence represents a number using digits 0s and 1s. You then perform BFS to find the lowest such number which is also a multiple of the input number.

This solution also leverages modulo (of the input number) to compute really large results. Full description available in the comments in the code.

You can also access the same code snippet in [ideone](https://ideone.com/2R2q34).

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    // Return the smallest multiple of the number (as a string) consisting only of digits 0 and 1
    //
    // All possible digits that can be constructed using the digits 0/1 can be represented
    // as a tree, where at each level, appending a 0 is one branch and appending a 1 is another
    //
    // If we perform BFS on this tree, the first number we see which is an exact multiple of the input
    // number will be the result (since it will be the smallest). Make sure to consider left
    // branch (i.e. 0) before considering the right branch (i.e. 1)
    //
    // The 2 paths we take at each level when the current number is num:
    //      (num * 10)
    //      (num * 10) + 1
    // 
    // Since the result can grow huge quite easily, it might not be possible to store the result in a
    // 32 or even a 64 bit int/long variable.
    //
    // One alternative is to use BigNumber, but a simpler alternative exists if we leverage modulo.
    //
    // The operations we perform above (i.e. multiplications and additions) will retain the useful part
    // of the result when using modulo. We use the given number itself as the modulo, and when we see a
    // result of 0, it means we have found a number which is an exact multiple of the input number.
    //
    // To reconstruct the number, we need to store the parent nodes of each node, when adding the node
    // in the queue (similar to using BFS for computing shortest path)
    //
    // We will also need to know if we appended a 0 or a 1 at each step, and so we add this information
    // as part of the node data structure as well.
    //
    // Re-visiting nodes is unecessary since we have seen this modulo result (i.e. value % num) already.
    // Any additional digits we add from now will only make the number longer and we already are tracking
    // the path for this same modulo result we've seen earlier.
    //
    public static String multiple(int num) {
        if (num < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid args");
        }

        String result = "0";

        if (num > 0) {
            // An array to mark all the visited nodes
            boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[num];
            Arrays.fill(isVisited, false);

            // The queue used by BFS
            Queue<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();

            // Add the first number 1 and mark it visited
            queue.add(new Node(true, 1 % num, null));
            isVisited[1 % num] = true;

            // The final destination node which represents the answer
            Node destNode = null;

            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                // Get the next node from the queue
                Node currNode = queue.remove();

                if (currNode.val == 0) {
                    // We have reached a valid multiple of num
                    destNode = currNode;
                    break;
                } else {
                    // Visit the next 2 neighbors
                    // Append 0 - (currNode.val * 10)
                    // Append 1 - (currNode.val * 10) + 1

                    // Append a '0'
                    int val1 = (currNode.val * 10) % num;
                    if (!isVisited[val1]) {
                        queue.add(new Node(false, val1, currNode));
                        isVisited[val1] = true;
                    }

                    // Append a '1'
                    int val2 = (val1 + 1) % num;
                    if (!isVisited[val2]) {
                        queue.add(new Node(true, val2, currNode));
                        isVisited[val2] = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Trace the path from destination to source
            if (destNode == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Result should not be null");
            } else {
                StringBuilder reverseResultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                Node currNode = destNode;
                while (currNode != null) {
                    reverseResultBuilder.append(currNode.isDigitOne ? '1' : '0');
                    currNode = currNode.parent;
                }
                result = reverseResultBuilder.reverse().toString();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Node represents every digit being appended in the decision tree
    private static class Node {
        // True if '1', false otherwise (i.e. '0')
        public final boolean isDigitOne;
        // The number represented in the tree modulo the input number
        public final int val;
        // The parent node in the tree
        public final Node parent;

        public Node(boolean isDigitOne, int val, Node parent) {
            this.isDigitOne = isDigitOne;
            this.val = val;
            this.parent = parent;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input number: " + num);
        System.out.println("Smallest multiple using only 0s and 1s as digits: " + Main.multiple(num));
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution overall. There is one problem, doesn't work for some higher integer values like 999999937 though it it well inside int range, because there is a multiplication by 10 (int val1 = (currNode.val * 10) % num;). To overcome this I replaced it by long tmp = currNode.val * 10;
               tmp = tmp % (long) num;
               int val1 = (int) tmp; Now it works and the output is : Input number: 99999937

Ans: 101010010110001000101100011
@Tuxdude

Answer (score 2):

How about this: you try a series of numbers :1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000,.....
and you divide each number by N and you record the remainder
 E.g. N = 9, 1/9 = 1  10 = 1(mod 9), 100 = 1(mod 9), ....
 The point is that you need to choose specific number from this series and make sure that these remainder add up to multiples times of N.
 E.g. N = 9, then you add 1, 10, 100, ....

I would suggest to use the algorithm: Once the sum of remainder of the series > N, try to search in remainder for remainders that sum up to N etc

Comment: Nice idea, but if you use the greedy approach, you'll always choose 1 first, so the N=4 example doesn't work.

Comment: Right, it is also possible that mathematically there is an algorithm(like transitions between binary and tenary). Then it will be very easy

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over a for loop ,convert the input number into binary,then convert the binary number to long and check whether the number is divisible by the input number.

here is the code:

```
private Long getno(int n) {

        for(int i=1;;i++)
        {
            String binary=Integer.toBinaryString(i);

            Long no=Long.parseLong(binary);

            if(no%n==0)
            {
                return no;
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have solved this in C, but still taking long time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getZeroOneMultipler(int number) {
  long multiplier = 1;
  while(1) {
    long product = multiplier++ * number;
    long temp = product;
    while ( temp != 0 ) {
      int digit = temp % 10;
      if ( digit != 0 && digit != 1 ) {
        break;
      }
      temp /= 10;
    }
    if ( temp == 0 ) {
      return product;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int i = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      printf("%d = %d\n", i, getZeroOneMultipler(i));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used Andrew's method

```
public class ZeroOne {
private int num;
private ArrayList<String> correctLeastSigDigit = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> toBeRemoved = new ArrayList<String>();

public ZeroOne(int num){
    this.num = num;
}

//get the number to multiply number to get a zero one
public int solve(){
    int digit =1;

    //get the least significant digits that will give is a 0 or 1 ending
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        String strNum = String.valueOf(this.num * i);
        if(checkLastSigDigits(strNum, 0) == true){
            correctLeastSigDigit.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }//for

    while(true){
        for(int i=0; i < correctLeastSigDigit.size(); i++){
            String temp = correctLeastSigDigit.get(i);
            for(int j=1; j < 10;j++){
                if(checkLastSigDigits(String.valueOf(this.num * Integer.valueOf("" + j + temp)),digit)){
                    if(isZeroOne(String.valueOf(this.num * Integer.valueOf("" + j + temp)))){
                        return this.num * Integer.valueOf("" + j + temp);
                    }
                    correctLeastSigDigit.add("" + j + temp);
                }
                toBeRemoved.remove(temp);
            }
        }
        for(String s: toBeRemoved){
            correctLeastSigDigit.remove(s);
        }
        digit++;
    }
}

public boolean checkLastSigDigits(String num, int n){
    for(int i=num.length() - 1; i >= num.length() - 1 - n; i--)
    if(num.charAt(i) != '1' && num.charAt(i) != '0'){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public boolean isZeroOne(String num){
    for(int i =0; i< num.length();i++){
        if(num.charAt(i) != '1' && num.charAt(i) != '0'){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
  {
    result = Convert.ToInt32( Convert.ToString(i, 2) );
    if (result % x == 0) break;  
  }

  Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Solution:

Smallest "Zero-One" number S can be any from {1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,. . . }, Which are binary numbers. so,

1. run through the loop
2. convert them in binary
3. divide by the number N and check for reminder.
4. print out the result.

   class Program
   {

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {

       int N;
       String Temp_S;
       int loop;
       int S;

       N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       for (loop = 1; loop <= 100; loop++)
       {
           Temp_S = Convert.ToString(loop, 2);
           S = Convert.ToInt32(Temp_S);
           if (S % N ==0)
           { 
           Console.WriteLine(S);
           Console.ReadLine();
           break;
       }
       }
   }
   ```

   }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Requirement: For any number N, find a number S (+ve integer) which is multiple of N but a zero-one number.
Brief Algorithm:
Start with 1 in a list.
Then iterate above list and compute following two values for every possible value of this list
`x = list[i]*10;`
`y = x+1;`
`dummylist.Add(x); dummyList.Add(y);`
`list = dummy;`

Here is C# code (a has some dummy value)

```
 long a = 88888;

        List<long> list = new List<long>();
        list.Add(1);
        bool flag = true;

        while (flag)
        {
            List<long> dummy = new List<long>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var r = list[i] * 10;
                var r1 = r + 1;
                if (r % a == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(r);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
                dummy.Add(r);
                dummy.Add(r1);
            }
            list = dummy;
        }
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),it will be useful to help you to raise your content quality

Answer (score 0):

```
BFS based Solution


import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Smallest_mul_0_1 {
    public static String multiple(int A) {
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        String res = "";
        queue.add(1);
        boolean found = false;
        while (!queue.isEmpty() && !found) {
            int num = queue.poll();
            if (num % A == 0) {
                res = num + "";
                found = true;
            }
            num *= 10;
            queue.add(num);
            queue.add(num + 1);
            System.out.println(queue);
        }
        return res;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result is:" + multiple(3));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example with performance made with c#.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        // //23799731 FINAL SOLUTION
        // 
        // //938213137
        // //1100001010001000001110100100111
        // //1100001010001000001110100100111
        // //1100001010011111111111111110111
        // 
        // //69999993

        struct Node
        {
            public int _mod;
            public byte _len;
        }

        static string GetOutput(Dictionary<Int64, Node> way1, Dictionary<Int64, Node> way2, Int64 linkPos, Int64 N)
        {
            string data = "";

            Int64 prev = linkPos;
            while (prev != 0)
            {
                Int64 temp = way1[prev]._mod;
                if (temp * 10 % N == prev)
                {
                    data = data + "0";
                }
                else if ((temp * 10 + 1) % N == prev)
                {
                    data = data + "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    data = data + "x";
                }
                prev = temp;
            }


            int size = data.Length;
            string strt = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                strt = strt + data[size - i - 1];
            }

            Int64 next = linkPos;
            while (next != 0)
            {
                Int64 temp = way2[next]._mod;
                if (next * 10 % N == temp)
                {
                    strt = strt + "0";
                }
                else if ((next * 10 + 1) % N == temp)
                {
                    strt = strt + "1";
                }
                else {
                    strt = strt + "x";
                }
                next = temp;
            }
            return strt;
        }

        static string DoubleBFS(Int64 N)
        {
            Dictionary<Int64, Node> way1 = new Dictionary<Int64, Node>();
            Dictionary<Int64, Node> way2 = new Dictionary<Int64, Node>();
            Queue<Node> que1 = new Queue<Node>();
            Queue<Node> que2 = new Queue<Node>();

            Node node;
            node._mod = 0;
            node._len = 0;
            way1[1] = node;

            node._mod = 1;
            node._len = 1;
            que1.Enqueue(node);

            for (Int64 i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Int64 mul = i * N;
                Int64 mod = mul % 10;
                if (mod == 0 || mod == 1)
                {
                    Int64 ddd = mul / 10;
                    node._mod = 0;
                    node._len = 0;
                    way2[ddd] = node;

                    node._mod = (int)ddd;
                    node._len = 1;
                    que2.Enqueue(node);
                }
            }

            Int64 linkPos = N;
            Int64 linkLen = N;
            string data = "";
            while (que1.Count > 0 && que2.Count > 0 && data.Length == 0)
            {
                if (way1.Count <= way2.Count)
                {
                    Node head = que1.Peek();
                    int levl = head._len;
                    while (que1.Count > 0)
                    {
                        head = que1.Peek();
                        if (head._len != levl) break;

                        Int64 temp = head._mod;
                        Int64 xxxx = (temp * 10) % N;
                        if (!way1.ContainsKey(xxxx))
                        {
                            way1[xxxx] = head;
                            node._mod = (int)xxxx;
                            node._len = (byte)(head._len + 1);
                            que1.Enqueue(node);
                        }

                        if (way2.ContainsKey(xxxx))
                        {
                            int linkLenNew = way2[xxxx]._len + way1[xxxx]._len;
                            if (linkLenNew < linkLen)
                            {
                                linkPos = xxxx;
                                linkLen = linkLenNew;
                            }
                        }

                        xxxx = (temp * 10 + 1) % N;
                        if (!way1.ContainsKey(xxxx))
                        {
                            way1[xxxx] = head;
                            node._mod = (int)xxxx;
                            node._len = (byte)(head._len + 1);
                            que1.Enqueue(node);
                        }

                        if (way2.ContainsKey(xxxx))
                        {
                            int linkLenNew = way2[xxxx]._len + way1[xxxx]._len;
                            if (linkLenNew < linkLen)
                            {
                                linkPos = xxxx;
                                linkLen = linkLenNew;
                            }
                        }
                        que1.Dequeue();
                    }

                    if (linkPos != N)
                    {
                        data = GetOutput(way1, way2, linkPos, N);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Node head = que2.Peek();
                    int levl = head._len;
                    while (que2.Count > 0)
                    {
                        head = que2.Peek();
                        if (head._len != levl) break;
                        for (Int64 i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                        {
                            Int64 mul = i * N + head._mod;
                            Int64 mod = mul % 10;
                            if (mod == 0 || mod == 1)
                            {
                                Int64 ddd = mul / 10;
                                if (!way2.ContainsKey(ddd))
                                {
                                    way2[ddd] = head;
                                    node._mod = (int)ddd;
                                    node._len = (byte)(head._len + 1);
                                    que2.Enqueue(node);
                                }
                                if (way1.ContainsKey(ddd))
                                {
                                    int linkLenNew = way2[ddd]._len + way1[ddd]._len;
                                    if (linkLenNew <= linkLen)
                                    {
                                        linkPos = ddd;
                                        linkLen = linkLenNew;

                                        string answ = GetOutput(way1, way2, linkPos, N);
                                        if (data.Length == 0 || data.CompareTo(answ) > 0)
                                        {
                                            data = answ;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        que2.Dequeue();
                    }
                }
            }
            return data;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Console.OpenStandardInput());
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
            Int64 T = Convert.ToInt64(sr.ReadLine());
            sw.WriteLine(DoubleBFS(T));
            sw.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code you please explain your code and how it solves the question being asked?

Comment: It's really not helpful to paste so long snippet with explaining nothing. Please consider adding explanations about what and how you do in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my algorithm:

1) Start with 10(binary 2).
2) convert this into string so it will be "10"
3) convert this string to decimal
4) divide this decimal by the input n.
5) add 1 in the binary number 10, result is 11
6) repeat 2-5 until the remainder is 0;

Comment: This sounds like a brute force approach, which OP already tried.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not sure how this is same as the brute force approach, as I understand the brute force approach will be to generate all the numbers like 1, 2, 3, 4.. [zero-one] and check for divisibility with all these number. Although I do think that my approach is same as Zeeshan's

Comment: Yes, your solution seems to be the same as Zeeshan's. You are looping through all possible solutions (i.e. 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000....), and checking each one for whether it is the solution. Any approach that potentially checks the whole solution space is brute force.